# Open git file with specific branch on Github from terminal

Tags: git, bash, github, terminal, git-bash

let's say I committed on local repo and pushed.. I want to open the project on GitHub and show files changes compared with the master branch or any other branch by one command, or at least copy the link to that into the clipboard, check this: [git open](https://github.com/paulirish/git-open), yet it's not enough.

I was thinking if it's possible to create a script using git commands and some other terminal tricks, things like : `git diff HEAD~ --name-only` `git remote -v`| any code that append to remote url' ?

The required command is :

```
github compareto master
```

or

`github commits`

or

```
github clipboard compareto master
```

Comment: something like this: https://github.com/Ketabuk/Ketabuk-Server/compare/laravel54...master ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not to reinvent the wheel. I found that git-open handles quite a few stuff so I forked it and added the functionality you wanted. [Here's my fork](https://gitlab.com/lordadamson/git-open).

You can now say `git open compareto <branch_name>` and it's gonna compare the current branch with the one you provided.

Or just `git open compareto` without providing a branch. if you're on any branch and you want to compare to master.